# xampp and phpMyAdmin not working

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp, mysql-error-1045

I'm using `xampp v3.2.2` and `phpMyAdmin 4.6.6`, I've already asked this but I didn't get any useful answer. When I try entering to `localhost/phpmyadmin`, I got this 2 errors:

> *#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)*

and

> *mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)*. I got this configuration on my config.inc.php:

```
<?php
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'xampp';

$i = 0;

$i++;

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = 'es_ES';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma__history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma__designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma__recent';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma__users';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma__usergroups';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma__navigationhiding';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] = 'pma__savedsearches';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] = 'pma__central_columns';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_settings'] = 'pma__designer_settings';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['export_templates'] = 'pma__export_templates';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] = 'pma__favorite';

?>
```

In:

```
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

I had:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
```

But when I put 'cookies' it "worked", but when I tried to login with any password it shows the error messages that I put before, and If I change the config of 'AllowNoPassword' from false to true, and put a password, when I try to login by username 'root' and the password I've put, it shows the same errors.

Comment: Did you assign all privileges to user?

Comment: Sorry but, how do i do that?

Comment: Check the answer. and don't forget to check that tick mark. If you don't know you can find it here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` and click on `user accounts` tab.
   [image]
2. Select your user `root` and click on `Edit privileges`

   [image]
3. Check all
   [image]
4. Then click on `go`

   [image]

It should work now

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get that bar when I enter localhost/phpmyadmin, I only get the "Welcome to phpMyAdmin" title, the lenguage selector and the login textboxes

Comment: username: root and leave password blank. Then click on login button

Comment: I get the error message #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)  and  mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO), the same if I set a password from the condifg.inc.php and use it with username root

Comment: Restart your xampp and let me know.

Comment: Still the same, I only stopped the Apache server and closed the window and opened it again

Comment: change `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';` to `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';` because mysqli is deprecated. Let me know if it works. Hope it works

Comment: Oh! you are using very old xampp. Please install new version of xampp. This caused the problem I think.

Comment: Still the same :/

Comment: I think xampp version caused it.

Comment: Install new version of xampp

Comment: Still the same errors, I installed xampp 7.1.1 and before I used 5.6.30

Comment: I think there is a problem in your system. maybe you can try wamp too. Don't get hurt.